# Lower font-size for all elements under tag by X or to X amount of their original values

Tags: html, css

I want to lower font-size for all elements under tag by X or to X amount of their original values, so that for example, when I "quote" someone, their text is copied completely, including H1, H2, Images, pre, etc, but with a smaller font or overall smaller footprint.

I am trying :

```
.text blockquote{
        *{
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    }
```

But, as expected, it will replace the font-size for all tags, either H1, H2, or other tags and make them all the same size.

I also tried a CSS 2D transform, scaling to 0.6%, applying a origin of 0% 0%, and a negative margin-bottom, but turned out a bit complicated to deal with, as it messed up other "blockquote" that had not elements inside them.

Is there a better approach?

Extra points: also scale down the images, like transform scale.

Comment: If you want some kind of cascading font-size, you may have to use the unit `em` for all the explicit set font-size of your elements (if the font-size is not set, it will inherit from the parent's font-size). So you can just change the font-size of the root element, then all the font-size of the child elements will change accordingly.

Comment: I am using bootstrap, so, I guess, I will have to manually set the font-sizes for all the allowed components?

Comment: I would do .text blockquote {font-size:60%} or any value you think is right. for image, you can set ma-width or max-height, transform:scale(x); will not be efficient to reduce actual size used by tags

Comment: What do you mean by “original values”? Can the markup and styling in the quoted text be anything, or is it under your control?  What does “under tag by X or to X amount” mean? Where did you try the code you included? It is not valid CSS and does not do anything in conforming CSS implementations. Please clarify by editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is to scale down font-size in blockquotes element, you may use % or em units to reset the reference of font-size to be used by childs : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nHrdK)**

```
blockquote {
  font-size:60%;
}
```

or **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/slmBt)**

```
blockquote {
  font-size:0.7em;
}
```